# Check whether the same app is running on different Android Device through NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I have to develop an Android app for NFC enabled Android Devices, If both phones come close listen for the intent that tells that phones are close by due to NFC. Please suggest any solution regarding that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What stops you from implementing exactly that?

Comment: @zapl I stops at as How we check that the same app is running on different Android Device or not? and How to interact with that device?

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried NFC enabling and disabling, and I get Data from another NFC Device. But i can't find that whether He is running the same app or not?

Comment: @CommonsWare And it is not just the application, Many things are there which are not shared with you.

Comment: -1 for what? Is the question not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't give enough information to answer your question, I can only guess at what you are trying to achieve.

You can create an application on each device that will send out NDEF messages. If both phones have this application installed, your NDEF message handling `Activity` will be started via an `Intent` when another NFC enabled phone with your application running gets close.

You should really read **thoroughly** the basic documentation provided to you at the android developer guide on NFC [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html).

Answer (score 0):

For an Android app on ICS (Android 4), you can use an [Android Application Record](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html#createApplicationRecord%28java.lang.String%29) in the NDEF message that you share via Android Beam (preferably as the last record in your message). This will guarantee that only your app will receive the message on the other device (or the user will be directed to the Google Play Store app to install it).